# 404 error on all endpoints in a basic flask app

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I recently completed a flask API tutorial from YouTube and I am now in the process of replicating what I learned in my own back end. Unfortunately after doing my own version of a what is only a little bit more complicated than a hello world in flask, I am getting a 404 error on my endpoints.

Here is my code so far:
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse, fields, marshal_with

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class Player(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"data" :"Hello"}
    def post(self):
        return 'Posted',200


if __name__ =="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have tried making a request to both endpoints ( get & post  to http://127.0.0.1:5000/player) and have done so from using a python script like the one below, a get request from my browser, and get & post requests from postman, and none have made my endpoints work. I have tried reinstalling flask and flask_restful with pip as well. I've also tried changing what I return, by either changing the object in my get request to a string, adding status codes, and removing status codes.

```
import requests
BASE = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"

response = requests.get(BASE + 'player')
print(response.json())
```

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `api.add_resource(Player, '/player')`

see example in [docs](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-api)